# Most efficient method of referencing large variables in user defined Python functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, optimization, arguments

I was wondering if there was a more efficient method of referencing large variables (such as arrays with hundreds of thousands of entries) from a function in Python than simply passing it in as an argument? I know `global` is an option, but it's so... unreliable, for lack of a better word, I pretty much consider it irrelevant (unless, perhaps, somebody can explain why this isn't the case). I ask because I recently wrote a script which calls the function:

```
def build(unique,gene,index): ###Concatenates entries from arguments into single string###
    ###Builds array from entries in all of unique's sublists###
    hold= []
    hold.append([category[index] for category in unique[1]])
    ###Builds a list of string concatenated from entries in other lists/arrays###
    line= ['\t'.join(gene[0:7]),'\t'.join(hold[0]),'\t'.join(gene[9:len(gene)])]
    ###Concatenates array in a single string###
    line= '\t'.join(line)
    return line
```

From the loop:

```
for gene in table[1:]:
    buffer.append(build(unique,gene,table.index(gene)))
```

The variable `unique` is an array with about 500k entries and the loop runs about 60k times. I understand that this is bound to take a while (it's currently sitting at about 12 minutes for this loop alone), but am hoping there's a way to optimize the method through which the `unique` is referenced in the function so a massive array doesn't have to be passed every time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're passing references to the array around. Not like a new copy is created for every function call.

Comment: It does appear there are issues with your code but what you mentioned is not one of them.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ What issues do you mean? I'll take any help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing large being passed here. `unique` is a reference to the same list every time; nothing is copied on a function call.

You will need to look elsewhere for optimisations.